# Pattern to redirect to a JSF ajax error page

Tags: ajax, jsf, error-handling

I would like for my app to redirect users encountering a JSF ajax error to a custom error page.

Here is what I have undertaken and where I met some issues:

```
var onError = function onError() {
   window.location = 'http://'+jQuery(location).attr('host')+'WEB-INF/include/error-pages/'+'ajaxError.html';//does not work of course!
 };
jsf.ajax.addOnError(onError);
```

Can anyone please provide advice on how to redirect to a page located within the WEB-INF folder?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The `/WEB-INF` folder is not publicitly available. The Servlet API specification forbids that as it's usually the folder to hold configuration files and template files which cannot be presented standalone. Put it somewhere outside `/WEB-INF` (and `/META-INF`) in public webcontent or create a public template which includes that error page.

Is it really an include page as its path suggests? Isn't it actually a full page as you're seem to be trying to show them in its full glory? That file should then definitely be placed outside `/WEB-INF`.

Comment: would specifying a 5XX `error-code` in web.xml have any effect?

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks. Then I won't serve it from web-inf if it is not possible.

Comment: @Varun, Thanks. I tried that but it does not work as 500 errors seems to be treated differently from ajax errors. By the way, what specific error code did you mean other than 500?

Comment: 500, 503 - Service Unavailable or 504 - Gateway Timeout

Comment: @Varun: that applies to synchronous requests only. For asynchronous (ajax) requests you need to handle it by `jsf.ajax.onError()` in client side or by a custom `ExceptionHandler` in server side.

Comment: BalusC: can you elaborate about the "custom ExceptionHandler on the server side" please?

Comment: This is offtopic so I won't update the answer, but here's a blog which covers it in detail: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2?force=756 You can just remove the `instanceof` check on `ViewExpiredException` to make it a global handler. If you want an example of me, ask a new and concrete question. I can't remember ever having answered it here on SO before, so sorry no link to old answers.